# Magento shows one price in store view and another in checkout/cart

Tags: price, magento1.9.3

Magento shows the customer one price in at the product level. And then, when added to cart, a different price. The configurable product as well as the other connected product also has a price of 299 SEK. So it's only at checkout and at cart 349 SEK is. 
There isn't or hasn't been any special prices on this product. It's only on this product.

Please help me!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There might be one of this issues causing that behaviour:

- price index is not uptodate
- your option value for color "Black" has a price set in the configurable product

Answer (score 0):

May be there is an issue with price display setting please check on

> Admin > System > Configuration > SALES > Tax

[image]

Comment: The price index is up to date, the display function is correct, however it is connected to both of the two products that are connected to the configurable one.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that the prices was collected from two other stores and not "inherited" from the default. Changing to default in all stores corrected this problem.

Thanks for all the help! =)